# Match function in VBA gives compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a work book with two Worksheets. '2020-2021' Worksheet has some unique numbers in its Column D. Result of Match should come to 'Arrears' Worksheet. C2 cell in 'Arrears' has a number which I want to Match in Column D in 2020-2021. Entered the following code.

```
Range("C3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("c2").value,Range('2020-2021'!d11:d206),0)
```

Gives Compile Error

Answer (score 6):

### Qualify (Use Variables)

- If you feel like learning something, study the first two versions.
- If not, pick one of the solutions in the third version.

**Qualify; what does that even mean?**

- Related to this case, e.g. `Range("C3")` is not qualified. We don't know for sure where it refers to (belongs). It is short for `ActiveSheet.Range("C3")` which means that if we select `Sheet1` it will refer to `C3` on `Sheet1`, if we select `Sheet2` it will refer to `C3` on `Sheet2` etc.
- But if we use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")` we have qualified the range and which ever worksheet we select, it will always refer to `C3` on worksheet `Sheet1` (Not 100% true because...).
- Similarly to the range case, we are saying that the worksheet in `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")` is not qualified. The expression is actually short for `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")`.
- To qualify it, we can do `Workbooks("Test.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")`. Now we are saying that the range is fully qualified, as is the worksheet. This might often seem unpractical, so `ThisWorkbook` 'comes to the rescue'.
- If you need to refer to the workbook containing this code, just use `ThisWorkbook`. You don't care if it is called `Test.xlsm` or `Last Years Official Inventory Report whatever.xlsm`... just use `ThisWorkbook`.
- Related to our case, we can then fully qualify our range using:

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Arrears").Range("C3")
  ```

**Application.Match vs WorksheetFunction.Match**

```
Sub qualifyAP()
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define worksheets.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("2020-2021")
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets("Arrears")
    
    ' Use the Application version of Match.
    Dim Result As Variant ' can hold any datatype incl. error value.
    Result = Application.Match(tgt.Range("C2").Value, src.Range("D11:D206"), 0)
    If Not IsError(Result) Then
        tgt.Range("C3").Value = Result
        'MsgBox "Data found and transferred."
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not found. Nothing done."
    End If

End Sub

Sub qualifyWF()
    
    ' Define workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define worksheets.
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("2020-2021")
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Set tgt = wb.Worksheets("Arrears")
    
    ' Use the WorksheetFunction version of Match.
    On Error Resume Next
    tgt.Range("C3").Value = WorksheetFunction.Match(tgt.Range("C2").Value, _
                                                    src.Range("D11:D206"), _
                                                    0)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "Data found and transferred."
    Else
        MsgBox "Data not found. Nothing done."
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Sub qualifyQF()
    
    Worksheets("Arrears").Range("C3").Value = WorksheetFunction _
      .Match(Worksheets("Arrears").Range("C2").Value, _
             Worksheets("2020-2021").Range("D11:D206"), _
             0)
' or:
    With Worksheets("Arrears")
        .Range("C3").Value = WorksheetFunction _
          .Match(.Range("C2").Value, _
                 Worksheets("2020-2021").Range("D11:D206"), _
                 0)
    End With
' or even:
    With Worksheets("Arrears").Range("C3")
        .Value = WorksheetFunction _
          .Match(.Offset(-1).Value, _
                 Worksheets("2020-2021").Range("D11:D206"), _
                 0)
    End With

End Sub
```