# to find the last used row count in every column using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the last used row count in every column of a particular sheet using VBA.I have written the code,but this prints only the row count of first column.Can you please help me to find the last used row in every column. Please find the code

```
Dim row As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim a As String
Dim b As Range
Dim myrange As Range
Dim count As Integer
Dim url As String
Dim lastRow, lRow As Long
Dim iCntr, jCntr, iMaxRow As Integer
Dim vMax
Dim arr2(18)


For iCntr = 1 To 18 ' for each column
     vMax = 0
     iMaxRow = 2
     
    'Finding last Row of current Column
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, iCntr).End(xlUp).row
    End With
    arr2(iCntr - 1) = lastRow
Next

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B18").Value = arr2
```

Comment: "the row count of first column for every column"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have written the code,but this prints only the row count of first column for every column.

There is no problem with your main code. The problem is with the way you are writing the output to "Sheet 1"

Change

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B18").Value = arr2
```

to

```
'~~> Note: It has to be 19 and not 18. If there are 18 columns and so on
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B19").Value = Application.Transpose(arr2)
```

**Tested on**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim arrLastRows(1 To 18) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
          
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Loop columns
        For i = 1 To 18
            'Get the last row of the current column
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            'Import the value to position i-7 (array start from 0)
            arrLastRows(i) = LastRow
        Next i
        
    .Range("T1:T18").Value = Application.Transpose(arrLastRows)
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Collect Last Rows

- The first code is a quick fix of your issues. It is still not recommended.
- The second code shows the advantages of using constants, of fully [qualify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64400323/match-function-in-vba-gives-compile-error/64401099#64401099)ing worksheets and ranges and of commenting your code (Be aware that this code is over-commented, you usually only comment sections of it.).

**Tips**

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) explains why we mostly do not use `Integer` any more.
- Try **avoiding** `Active` in any flavor i.e. `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell`.
- Use variables. Use meaningful names (poorly demonstrated). Additionally maybe make up names for them.
- Be careful when declaring variables in one line: `Dim x As..., y As..., z As...`.
- In the second code, if declaring variables as they are needed is too confusing at this stage, copy all those `Dim`s to the beginning of the code right after the constants to make it more readable for you.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LastRowsQF()
    Dim row As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As Range
    Dim myrange As Range
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim url As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, lRow As Long
    ' Not:
    'Dim lastRow, lRow As Long ' Wrong!
    Dim iCntr As Integer, jCntr As Integer, iMaxRow As Integer
    ' Not:
    'Dim iCntr, jCntr, iMaxRow As Integer ' Wrong!
    Dim vMax
    ' This means 18 rows by 1 column.
    Dim arr2(1 To 18, 1 To 1)
    ' Not:
    ' This means 1 row with 19 columns (elements)!
    'Dim arr2(18)
    
    For iCntr = 1 To 18 ' for each column
         'vMax = 0 ' Not used.
         'iMaxRow = 2 '  Not used.
         
        'Finding last Row of current Column
        With ActiveSheet
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, iCntr).End(xlUp).row
        End With
        arr2(iCntr, 1) = lastRow
    Next
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B19").Value = arr2

End Sub

Sub LastRows()
    
    ' Constants
    Const srcNumberOfColumns As Long = 18 ' Source Number of Columns
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet1"    ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const tgtFirstCell As String = "B2"   ' Target First Cell Range Address
    
    ' Define workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containig this code.
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet ' e.g. wb.worksheets("Sheet2") is preferred.
    
    ' Define (2D one-based one-column) Data Array ('Data').
    Dim Data As Variant
    ReDim Data(1 To srcNumberOfColumns, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Write last row of each column to rows of Data Array.
    Dim j As Long
    For j = 1 To srcNumberOfColumns
        Data(j, 1) = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, j).End(xlUp).row
    Next
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet ('ws').
    ' Note: Use a different variable if you still need to use Source Worksheet.
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtName)
    
    ' Define Target Range ('rng').
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws.Range(tgtFirstCell).Resize(UBound(Data, 1))
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Target Range.
    rng.Value = Data

End Sub
```